# devExpress ASPxCallbackPanel cant use 2 user controllls in same page... it wont popup

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

```
<dx:ASPxCallbackPanel ID="callbackPanelSharingControl" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="callbackPanelSharingControl"
    OnCallback="callbackPanelSharingControl_Callback">
    <PanelCollection>
        <dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent1" runat="server">
            <div onclick="" class="" style="text-align: center;" runat="server" id="divVisionBoardSharing">
                <div style="float: left;">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgSharingBoxIcon" runat="server" Style="width: 30px;" />
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSharintBoxText" runat="server" Text="Shared Control Not Activated"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="popupControlSharingControl" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="popupControlSharingControl"
                ShowHeader="False">
                <ContentCollection>
                    <dx:PopupControlContentControl runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
                        <div onclick="popupControlSharingControl.Hide(); callbackPanelSharingControl.PerformCallback('sharingchangesave;0');"
                            class="sharing-button-main" style="float: right;">
                            Save Option
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear: both;">
                        </div>
                    </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
                </ContentCollection>
            </dx:ASPxPopupControl>
        </dx:PanelContent>
    </PanelCollection>
</dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>
```

if i put 2 user controls in a page with reference ofcourse... only the last one will popup and work... first one doesnt popup on click... i think somethings wrong with the callback.. eny ideeas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this issue, because you have two ASPxCallbackPanels with the same ClientInstanceName.  In this case, the PerformCallback method of the last panel is called.
A possible solution is to define the CallbackPanel's ClientInstanceName dynamically.  Also, you will have to use a server side DIV element to set its onclick event in code behind.